# IntelliJ and Gradle accessing the resources directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I am trying to access the resources directory in IntelliJ and am using the "default" layout from Gradle.

```
src
├── main
│   └── java
├── resources
└── test
    └── java
```

Now, when I try:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/");
```

I expect it to lead me to the resource directory, but instead it leads me to

```
/build/classes/test/
```

(path given from the project root).

I figured out how to access the `resources` directory in an ugly way:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/");
Path path = Paths.get(url.toString()).getParent().resolve("resources")
```

That leads me to the following directory:

```
/build/classes/resources
```

Is there an easier or more beautiful way to do it?

Comment: That's not default layout. By default there are 2 resources folders under the main and test source sets.

Comment: @Stanislav 
As I understand you these resource folders have to be in the following directions:
`/src/main/resource` and `/src/test/resource`?

Comment: Yes, right there https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N152C8

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem solved!